# How do these 2 ways of printing floats with decimal part differs?

Tags: c++, c++17

How do these 2 ways of printing floats with decimal part differs?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std; 
int main() {
    float n; 
    cin >> n; 
    printf("%.2f\n", n);
    printf("%.*f\n", 2, n);
}
```

Comment: There's no difference, I would say. Both request 2 decimal places after the decimal point.

Comment: Both don't compile

Comment: It's strange to mix `cin` with `printf`. Better to use `cout` with [`setprecision`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setprecision).

Comment: why is it strange ?

Comment: what are the differences ?

Answer (score 1):

I cleaned up your code a bit. I have a few comments:

1. With some compilers, you'll get a warning. It's better to use double than float.
2. As written, they both print output as 3.12 (for instance).
3. The second form lets you use a variable to control the precision, where the first has fixed precision. So as written, it's identical, but the second form is more flexible. It's also just a little harder to use.

Comment: why is it better to use a double instead of a float